# php assigning values to array variables before it is created

Tags: php

Program 1 and Program 2 are supposed to output same values but they are not. Why? How to assign values to array variables before it is being created?

```
<?php
echo "Program 1.<br>";
$col = array(1,3);
$data = array("123,234,345,456,567", "234,345,456,567,678");
$resultfinal = "";
for($i=0; $i<count($data); ++$i){
    $tempdata = explode(',',$data[$i]);
    for($j=0; $j<count($col); ++$j){
        $resultfinal .= ",".$tempdata[$col[$j]];
    }
    $resultfinal .= "<br>";
}
echo $resultfinal;

echo "Program 2.<br>";
$resultfinal2 = "";
$resultsub = "";
for($j=0; $j<count($col); ++$j){
    $resultsub .= ",".$tempdata2[$col[$j]]; 
} 
for($i=0; $i<count($data); ++$i){
    $tempdata2 = explode(',',$data[$i]);
    $resultfinal2 .= $resultsub."<br>";
}
echo $resultfinal2;

?>
```

Output:

```
Program 1.
,234,456
,345,567
Program 2.
error...
```

Comment: can you tell me which output you want ? with array that you given?

Comment: Program 2 j loop runs once only to save cpu time but it doesn't work. There should be a way to format variables so that i loop can use it correctly. Any idea? thanks.

Comment: Hi Albert Akki, program 1 gives correct output but not program 2, by right both programs should output same result

Comment: your  program 2 output is ,345,567,345,567  and you want same output is 234,456 ,345,567 ?

Comment: If I'm not wrong you need to skip 3 values from the second array

Comment: i think you need to use this. 
<?php 


$test = explode(",",$data[1]);
array_pop($test);
echo implode($test,","); 

?>

Comment: First array says in each row of array $data pick column 1 and column 3 values. Program 1 is picking the correct values but not program 2.

Comment: In program 2 loop j I am assigning value in $tempdata to $resultsub but $tempdata has not been created yet as it will only be created at loop i, below loop j. Can I do that? if not how?

Comment: Updated to so that variables are not reuse.

Comment: `$resultsub .= ",".$tempdata2[$col[$j]];` - $tempdata2 is NULL.

Comment: You cannot save CPU time this way. Think a little about it: you need to process all the items from `$data` (1 loop over `$data`). For each item from `$data` you need to explode it into pieces then extract the values whose indices are stored in `$col`. This is another loop (over `$col`) for each item of `$data`. The only way to do this is to use two nested loops (outer loop over `$data`, inner loop over `$col`) as you already did in program 1. If you are really concerned about saving CPU time (not a real concern for small and medium amounts of data), investigate using more PHP array functions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save CPU time this way.

Think a little about it: you need to process **all the items** from `$data` (1 loop over `$data`). For each item from `$data` you need to explode it into pieces then extract the values whose indices are stored in `$col`. This is another loop (over `$col`) **for each item** of `$data`.

The only way to do this is to use two nested loops (outer loop over `$data`, inner loop over `$col`) as you already did in program 1.

If you are really concerned about saving CPU time (not a real concern for small and medium amounts of data), you can try using less PHP code and more [internal PHP array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) (to move the loops and as much processing as possible into the PHP's native code):

This is a possible solution:

```
// For array_intersect_key() we need an array having the values of $col as keys
$columns = array_combine($col, $col);

// Store the generated lines here
$output  = array();

// The outer loop over $data
foreach ($data as $item) {
    // Explode the item into pieces
    $pieces = explode(',', $item);
    // Move the inner loop into PHP native code; array_intersect_key() keeps
    // from $pieces the values having the same keys as $columns
    // implode() joins the extracted pieces back into a string
    $output[] = implode(',', array_intersect_key($pieces, $columns));
}
// Join the lines with <br>, output them
echo(implode("<br>\n", $output));
```